# 2010 ford edge headlights

Tags: ford

I took my edge to have the brake booster replaced and when I went to get the car the headlights didn't come on when on low beam but the hi beams work we checked all the plugs and they are plugged in correct what could be the problem

Comment: Fuse or relay. I'd start there.

Comment: This may sound trivial, but were the headlights set to auto when you took it in? This happened to me when I took my 2010 Milan in for service. They switched it to "Off" during their checks and I didn't notice, so I was alarmed when they didn't come on when expected. Otherwise, I would take it back to them. They may have disconnected something while performing maintenance and failed to reconnect it.